# How to obtain Gmail message identifier in Alternative Runtime?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace-add-ons

I am developing GWAO using Java based on the Alternative Runtime. After two sleepless days, I finally set up an Addon to extend the Gmail Compose editor by defining composeTrigger in the deployment resource.

```
# deployment.json
{
"gmail": {
      "composeTrigger": {
        "draftAccess": "METADATA",
        "actions": [{
          "runFunction": "https://.../gmail/draft",
          "label": "Draft"
        }]
      }
    },
}
```

I also successfully initiated callback function calls to my REST endpoint when the user clicked a button in my Addon. The callback function(rest endpoint), triggered by the Button, was intended to insert some text based on current message content into the compose box. But neither the messageId of GmailEventObject was populated, nor the threadId and accessToken. However, I could see the draft subject and other metadata. After digging into the request body of the RPC from Google-side, I realized all these properties were not included in the request. Here is a snippet of the request:

```
{
    "commonEventObject": {
        "hostApp": "GMAIL",
        "platform": "WEB",
        "formInputs": {
           ....
         }
    },
    "gmail": {
        "toRecipients": [
            "..."
        ],
        "subject": "..."
    },
    "authorizationEventObject": {
        "userOAuthToken": "...",
        "systemIdToken": "..."
    }
   }
```

How could I let Google include this data? According to sample codes inside the official document regarding Alternative Runtime [document](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/guides/alternate-runtimes),  I assumed this should be included in the request with no effort.

Do I need to do something before this to prompt authorization?

I attempted to adjust by requesting the scope inside the deployment resource document, but I got no luck.

```
#DEPLOYMENT.JSON
{
 "oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.action.compose", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.metadata", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.readonly"]
}
```

Comment: I've been having a similar experience, but a different problem! The requests sent to my endpoint do have the message id and thread id, but they don't have "formInputs" in the event object! Here's the scopes from my deployment resource:

  "oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly"]